# C++ API to get the private and virtual bytes consumed by a process

Tags: c++, winapi

Is there an API provided by Microsoft to get the private and virtual bytes consumed by a process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GetProcessMemoryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682050(v=vs.85).aspx) could be of great use.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the answer by DumbCoder which amongst others gives you physical memory usage, you should also take a look at [`GlobalMemoryStatusEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366589(v=vs.85).aspx).

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965225(v=vs.85).aspx) you can find the definition of *virtual bytes*  according to Microsoft and how you can derive it as a simple difference from two counters that `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` provides.

Notes of caution:

- The function `GlobalMemoryStatusEx` has mixed purpose since it provides information about the system as a whole and information specific to the calling process, e.g. virtual memory usage.
- Read/apply the API carefully otherwise you can end up with broken counters.